# Custom UICollectionViewCell can't set proerty value

Tags: ios

I'm trying to set a property on my custom `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Setup cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"IgCell";

    PAInterestGraphCell *cell = (PAInterestGraphCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.interestCategory = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Return the cell
    return cell;

}
```

The `PAInterestGraphCell` code:

```
@interface PAInterestGraphCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (atomic, retain) PAInterestCategory *interestCategory;

@end


#import "PAInterestGraphCell.h"
#import "PAScaleView.h"

@implementation PAInterestGraphCell

@synthesize interestCategory;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        PAScaleView *scaleView = [[PAScaleView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        scaleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        scaleView.interestCategory = self.interestCategory;

        [self.contentView addSubview:scaleView];
    }

    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

But when I access the `interestCategory` property in `initWithFrame` it has lost all the values.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: When and where do ever set any values for interestCategory? I see that you do that in the table view, but why would you expect it to have any value in the init method?

Comment: I add 8 instances of the `PAInterestCategory` to the `dataArray`, and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I get the one at the index, and assign it to the cell.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but in your question, you say that it's nil in the init method -- why would you expect it to have any value there? You haven't set it yet at that point.

Comment: What method should I override in my cell, where I can add the subview and get the value, then?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're trying to do -- you don't "get" values from cells, you set values on them from your array. What are you seeing with the current code? Are the cells populated?

Comment: Everything is populated. Within my cell I want to add a `PAScaleView` which is a drawing using `UIBezierPath`. That class needs the `PAInterestCategory` in order to make the drawing. Since I set the `PAInterestCategory` on the cell, I thought I could send it along down to the `PAScale` view. But apparently, I'm doing it 'too early'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20814/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-martinhn)

Answer (score 0):

"`@synthesize`" accessors might not be fully created until the conclusion of the "`init`" methods, so if you need to get access to them during your "`init`" method you need to use a static variable or an ivar (and then have your "`@synthesize`" point to them and use "`self.`" in everything outside of the "`init`").

Plus it seems kind of senseless that you want to access an "`interestCategory`" property that couldn't have been set prior to object instantiation and initialization.  Or is that a line of code you left out from your cut & paste?

Comment: What line are we talking about, regarding access to the interestCategory?

Comment: The "`scaleView.interestCategory = self.interestCategory;`" line, in your "`init`" method. I don't see where it was initialized within your `init` method. And it couldn't have been initialized *before* you called "`alloc`" & "`init`" on it, could it??

Comment: It should be set in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method: `cell.interestCategory = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: "`initWithFrame`" should get called the first bunch of times "`cellForItemAtIndexPath`" gets called, until enough cells appear to fill the screen and then "`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`" doesn't have to instantiate additional cells and instead can recycle previously-used (and offscreen) cells. You need to set your "`interestCategory`" property either via a static or "`PAInterestGraphCell`" object ivar, or set it via the property accessor somewhere else other than your "`PAInterestGraphCell`" object init.